# Setting up DD-WRT behind a DSL router/modem from ISP

Tags: dd-wrt

Okay so I bought a Buffalo WBMR-HP-G300H the first router/modem that supports DD-WRT, after having managed to get dd-wrt to run on the router without problems the next step was to plug my dsl cable from my isp into it.

The supported adsl standards of my ISP are:
ITU G.992.1 (ADSL-G.DMT)
ITU G.992.2 (ADSL-G.Lite)
ITU G.992.3 (ADSL2)
ITU G.992.5 (ADSL2+)

But when I access my DD-WRT setup page I can only see 
Annex A
Annex A T1
Annex A Lite
Annex A DMT
Annex A ADSL2
Annex A ADSL2+
Annex L
Annex B
Annex B DMT
Annex B ADSL2
Annex B ADSL2+
Annex M
Annex M ADSL2
Annex M ADSL2+

After consulting 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line#ADSL_standards

Not much has remained clear in terms of which one should I choose or are even the ones I need available. My connection speed is 80/10mbit/s

As this is the configuration on my ISP router/modem
Encapsulation: 1483 Bridged IP LLC
VPI: 1
VCI: 64
Bridge Mode: Enabled

But regardless the dd-wrt router just does not work, the dsl just blinks periodically and that is it.

Now the second thing that I have attempted to do is to just connect my dd-wrt rotuer to my ISP router but the two just do not play well with each other at all.

I select the Automatic Configuration - DCHP
I ve set the router IP ( dd-wrt ) to be 192.168.1.50 just to test things out, while the IP of the ISP router is 192.168.1.1

One strange thing to me is that when I select Automatic Configuration  DHCP is that it is still asking me for the Annex Type VPI/VCI etc... even though I am just configuring the LAN ports on both ends.

I am sorry if my description is not the best I really am, if you require additional information please ask I will provide it promptly.

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0):

I know the question's been 2 years ago, but Annex A vs Annex B, is something you've most likely already heard as: isdn vs pstn ...

The standard protocol for ISPs is pstn, (if i'm not mistaken, isdn offers a fax line in addition to your telephone line - that is regarding real world ups & downs), therefore, I'm betting you should be using Annex A.

Else, switch over to Annex B (which means your ISP is providing you services over isdn).